# Handling lots of UDP packets in python

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I'm developing a program in Python that uses UDP to receive data from an FPGA (a data collector device). The speed is very high, about 54 MB/s at the highest setting, that's why we use a dedicated gigabit ethernet connection. My problem is: a lot of packages get lost. This is not a momentary problem, the packets come in for a long time, then there's a few seconds long pause, then everything seems fine again. The pause depends on the speed (faster communication, more lost).

I've tried setting buffers higher, but something seems to be missing. I've set `self.sock_data.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_RCVBUF,2**28)` to increase buffer size along with the matching kernel option: `sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=268435456`.

Packages have an internal counter, so I know which one got lost (also, I use this to fix their order). An example: 11s of data lost, around 357168 packages. (I've checked, and it's not a multiple of an internal buffer size in either of my program or the FPGA's firmware). I'm watching the socket on a separate thread, and immediately put them into a Queue to save everything.

What else should I set or check?

Comment: I'd guess, python would be able to perform okayish under `54 MB/s`, but i have not tested. Anything, that requires speed, one wouldn't normally use python. I suggest you use C++ or something for this :)

Comment: You say you watch the socket in another "thread" - but are you actually using another real thread/process, or is this a Python "thread" which would still get locked by [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)? Have you tried putting the watcher into one or more separate _processes_?

Comment: And, did you try `twisted` or something. Programming using bare `socket` is not a good idea for this :)

Comment: I like C++, but for this project that's not an option. Mostly because we're almost done, and also, because in this field, most of the data processing algos are written (and already available) in Python. The speed is all right - apart from this glitch.

Comment: I'm using the threading library, bare sockets without twisted.

Comment: Would it be hard to replace the packet receive part with `twisted` ?

Comment: I've never used twisted, so I don't know. If it solves this problem, I'll put it into my code. Networking is separate in my side, and - because of the FPGA's properties - command uses a separate socket/port/everything. So if I can replace only the data socket with twisted, it's no problem. I'll go and find a tutorial.